# No such a module error on TodayViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, ios10-today-widget

I've an extra target which is a today widget. I'm trying to add some pods to this target, but I'm getting no such a module 'xxx' when I try to import a module, by the way it's working on my main target. here is what I've already done,

podfile

```
target 'My-Project' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'SwiftyUserDefaults'
    pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'
end

target 'My-Widget' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'SwiftyUserDefaults'
    pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

- pod installed with no error.
- project opened by .xcworkspace
- `pod --version` is 1.0.1
- I've cleared derived data, cleaned project, reopened project and rebuild project **several times**.

How can I make it work?

And the result is
[image]

Comment: are you sure alamofire works fine?

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok, no it's not working either. but both of them working for main target.

Comment: if I were you, I would try first to update cocoapods to newest version (1.1.1 as far as i know) and try to reinstall pods from scratch (maybe with pod deintegrate even).

Comment: BTW have you tried it on a clean empty project?

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok, nope. let me try update cocoapods and try it on a clean project.

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok, :) thanks, updating cocoapods to 1.1.1 solved my problem. it's working....

Comment: glad to help! should I write it as an answer?

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok, sure you should do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like cocoapods version is a bit outdated. In some cases (especially considering constantly changing swift, xcode and cocoapods) it might lead to frustrating consequences. Fortunately, this one was easy to fix by updating cocoapods.